# Actualizar valores en formulario django con javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

Soy bastante nuevo con todo el tema de Javascript, y no consigo encontrar solucion a mi problema.

Tengo un proyecto de django en el cual una de las partes es para crear facturas, tengo toda la parte del backend funcional pero cuando en mi html para generar la factura elijo un producto, no me actualizad de manera automática el campo precio unitario, pero si me actualiza el total de ese producto. Tampoco me actualiza el campo subtotal ni el total de la factura.

Este es mi codigo JS:

```
// Funcion para calcular totales
$(document).ready(function () {
    function updateTotals(){

    
    //$('#id_line_one_quantity, #id_line_one_unit_price, #id_line_two_quantity, #id_line_two_unit_price, #id_line_three_quantity, #id_line_three_unit_price, #id_line_four_quantity, #id_line_four_unit_price, #id_line_five_quantity, #id_line_five_unit_price, #id_line_six_quantity, #id_line_six_unit_price, #id_line_seven_quantity, #id_line_seven_unit_price, #id_line_eight_quantity, #id_line_eight_unit_price, #id_line_nine_quantity, #id_line_nine_unit_price, #id_line_ten_quantity, #id_line_ten_unit_price, #id_vat, #id_discount').keyup(function(){
        var line_one_quantity_text = $('#id_line_one_quantity').val();
        var line_one_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_one').val();
        var line_one_total = parseFloat(line_one_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_one_unit_price_text);

        var line_two_quantity_text = $('#id_line_two_quantity').val();
        var line_two_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_two').val();
        var line_two_total = parseFloat(line_two_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_two_unit_price_text);

        var line_three_quantity_text = $('#id_line_three_quantity').val();
        var line_three_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_three').val();
        var line_three_total = parseFloat(line_three_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_three_unit_price_text);

        var line_four_quantity_text = $('#id_line_four_quantity').val();
        var line_four_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_four').val();
        var line_four_total = parseFloat(line_four_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_four_unit_price_text);

        var line_five_quantity_text = $('#id_line_five_quantity').val();
        var line_five_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_five').val();
        var line_five_total = parseFloat(line_five_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_five_unit_price_text);

        var line_six_quantity_text = $('#id_line_six_quantity').val();
        var line_six_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_six').val();
        var line_six_total = parseFloat(line_six_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_six_unit_price_text);

        var line_seven_quantity_text = $('#id_line_seven_quantity').val();
        var line_seven_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_seven').val();
        var line_seven_total = parseFloat(line_seven_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_seven_unit_price_text);

        var line_eight_quantity_text = $('#id_line_eight_quantity').val();
        var line_eight_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_eight').val();
        var line_eight_total = parseFloat(line_eight_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_eight_unit_price_text);

        var line_nine_quantity_text = $('#id_line_nine_quantity').val();
        var line_nine_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_nine').val();
        var line_nine_total = parseFloat(line_nine_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_nine_unit_price_text);

        var line_ten_quantity_text = $('#id_line_ten_quantity').val();
        var line_ten_unit_price_text = $('#unit-price_ten').val();
        var line_ten_total = parseFloat(line_ten_quantity_text) * parseFloat(line_ten_unit_price_text);

        var subtotal = line_one_total + line_two_total + line_three_total + line_four_total + line_five_total + line_six_total + line_seven_total + line_eight_total + line_nine_total + line_ten_total;
        var subtotalRounded = subtotal.toFixed(2);
        var vat = $('#id_vat').val();
        var total_vat = vat / 100;
        var discount = $('#id_discount').val();
        var total = subtotal + (subtotal * total_vat) - (subtotal * discount / 100);
        var totalRounded = total.toFixed(2);

        $('#id_line_one_total_price').val(line_one_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_two_total_price').val(line_two_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_three_total_price').val(line_three_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_four_total_price').val(line_four_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_five_total_price').val(line_five_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_six_total_price').val(line_six_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_seven_total_price').val(line_seven_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_eight_total_price').val(line_eight_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_nine_total_price').val(line_nine_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_line_ten_total_price').val(line_ten_total.toFixed(2));
        $('#id_subtotal').val(subtotalRounded);
        $('#id_vat').val(vat);
        $('#id_discount').val(discount);
        $('#id_total').val(totalRounded);
    }
    updateTotals();

    $('#id_line_one_quantity, #id_line_one_unit_price, #id_line_two_quantity, #id_line_two_unit_price, #id_line_three_quantity, #id_line_three_unit_price, #id_line_four_quantity, #id_line_four_unit_price, #id_line_five_quantity, #id_line_five_unit_price, #id_line_six_quantity, #id_line_six_unit_price, #id_line_seven_quantity, #id_line_seven_unit_price, #id_line_eight_quantity, #id_line_eight_unit_price, #id_line_nine_quantity, #id_line_nine_unit_price, #id_line_ten_quantity, #id_line_ten_unit_price, #id_vat, #id_discount').keyup(function(){
        updateTotals();
    });
    setInterval(updateTotals, 1000);

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Obtén el elemento donde mostrarás el precio unitario
    var unitPriceElement_one = $('#unit-price_one');
    var unitPriceElement_two = $('#unit-price_two');
    var unitPriceElement_three = $('#unit-price_three');
    var unitPriceElement_four = $('#unit-price_four');
    var unitPriceElement_five = $('#unit-price_five');
    var unitPriceElement_six = $('#unit-price_six');
    var unitPriceElement_seven = $('#unit-price_seven');
    var unitPriceElement_eight = $('#unit-price_eight');
    var unitPriceElement_nine = $('#unit-price_nine');
    var unitPriceElement_ten = $('#unit-price_ten');

    // Obtén el precio unitario original del primer producto
    var originalUnitPrice_one = parseFloat($('#id_line_one_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_two = parseFloat($('#id_line_two_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_three = parseFloat($('#id_line_three_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_four = parseFloat($('#id_line_four_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_five = parseFloat($('#id_line_five_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_six = parseFloat($('#id_line_six_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_seven = parseFloat($('#id_line_seven_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_eight = parseFloat($('#id_line_eight_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_nine = parseFloat($('#id_line_nine_unit_price').val());
    var originalUnitPrice_ten = parseFloat($('#id_line_ten_unit_price').val());
    




    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto1)
    $('#id_line_one').on('change', function() {
        var productId_one = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_one === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_one.val(originalUnitPrice_one.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_one + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_one.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_one').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_one.val(originalUnitPrice_one.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });


    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto2)
    $('#id_line_two').on('change', function() {
        var productId_two = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_two === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_two.val(originalUnitPrice_two.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_two + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_two.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_two').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_two.val(originalUnitPrice_two.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });







    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto3)
    $('#id_line_three').on('change', function() {
        var productId_three = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_three === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_three.val(originalUnitPrice_three.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_three + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_three.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_three').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_three.text(originalUnitPrice_three.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });





    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto4)
    $('#id_line_four').on('change', function() {
        var productId_four = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_four === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_four.val(originalUnitPrice_four.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_four + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_four.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_four').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_four.val(originalUnitPrice_four.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });





    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto5)
    $('#id_line_five').on('change', function() {
        var productId_five = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_five === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_five.val(originalUnitPrice_five.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_five + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_five.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_five').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_five.val(originalUnitPrice_five.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });




    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto6)
    $('#id_line_six').on('change', function() {
        var productId_six = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_six === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_six.val(originalUnitPrice_six.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_six + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_six.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_six').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_six.val(originalUnitPrice_six.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });





    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto7)
    $('#id_line_seven').on('change', function() {
        var productId_seven = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_seven === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_seven.val(originalUnitPrice_seven.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_seven + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_seven.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_seven').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_seven.val(originalUnitPrice_seven.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });




    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto8)
    $('#id_line_eight').on('change', function() {
        var productId_eight = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_eight === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_eight.val(originalUnitPrice_eight.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_eight + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_eight.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_eight').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_eight.val(originalUnitPrice_eight.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });




    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto9)
    $('#id_line_nine').on('change', function() {
        var productId_nine = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_nine === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_nine.val(originalUnitPrice_nine.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_nine + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_nine.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_nine').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_nine.val(originalUnitPrice_nine.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });





    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo de selección (producto10)
    $('#id_line_ten').on('change', function() {
        var productId_ten = $(this).val(); // Obtén el ID del producto seleccionado
        if (productId_ten === '') {
            // Si no se selecciona un producto, restaura el precio unitario original
            unitPriceElement_ten.val(originalUnitPrice_ten.toFixed(2) + ' $');
        } else {
            // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el precio del producto
            $.ajax({
                url: '/management/get_product_price/' + productId_ten + '/',  // Ruta a tu vista Django para obtener el precio
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Actualiza el precio unitario en la página
                    unitPriceElement_ten.val(response.unit_price);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("No se actualizó el precio")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Maneja el evento de cambio en el campo para quitar el producto
    $('#id_line_ten').on('clear', function() {
        // Restablece el precio unitario al valor original al quitar un producto
        unitPriceElement_ten.val(originalUnitPrice_ten.toFixed(2) + ' $');
    });

});
```

¿Qué es lo que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Has publicado una gran cantidad de código en Javascript, que, además, parece estar incompleto sin el HTML relacionado. Funciona mejor cuando preparas un [mcve] con el que quien quiera responderte pueda reproducir el problema (completo), contenga solo el código esencial para reproducirlo (mínimo) y así tenga un punto de partida para una posible respuesta. Eso aumentaría tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Encontrarás más información en [ask]. Un saludo.